# PHP mysql write lock doesn't allow updating database. Connection which locks should be able to update

Tags: php, database, mysqli, pdo, locking

I'm trying to lock (WRITE) a table in database, and while it's locked I want to update some field and then unlock table. It seems that once I lock a table, the connection which locked table in also locked out. But the point of WRITE lock is to disable other connections, but not the one doing the locking. I tried it using mysqli and PDO, but none of it seems to work.

I also tried directly in phpmyadmin, and it works fine.

I'm using PHP 5.6 and mysqli/PDO extensions. 
If I execute it directly in phpmyadmin than it works:

```
LOCK TABLE `catalogue_user` WRITE;
UPDATE `catalogue_user` SET update_time = NOW() WHERE catalogue_user_id = 5;
SELECT SLEEP(10);
SELECT NOW();
```

I need "update_time" to be updated immediately after locking (while others can't access table)

```php
try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=". DB_HOST .";dbname=". DB_DBNAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
        // set the PDO error mode to exception
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        echo "Connected successfully";

        var_dump(date("H:i:s"));

        $conn->exec("LOCK TABLE ". DB_TABLE_CATALOGUE_USER ." WRITE;");
        $conn->exec("UPDATE ". DB_TABLE_CATALOGUE_USER ." SET update_time = '". date("H:i:s") ."' WHERE catalogue_user_id = 5");

        sleep(10);

        $conn->exec("UNLOCK TABLES;");

        var_dump(date("H:i:s"));

      }
      catch(PDOException $e)
      {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
      }
```

I've searched allover for possible clues, but none of them worked...

Comment: It should be `LOCK TABLES` not `LOCK TABLE`.

Comment: I think it works with both, TABLES and TABLE. Check here: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-table-locking/ . Anyway, tried to change it, but result is the same.

Comment: Actually what happens now is that UPDATE is triggered two times. Once when locking is started and once when finished. I'm really confused about this... How is it even possible?

Comment: Because you are calling this script two times

Comment: I'm not doing that :)